# deadlock and mutual exclusion

Tags: deadlock, mutual-exclusion

Two processes X and Y need to access a critical section. Consider the following synchronization construct used by both the processes.

http://d18khu5s3lkxd9.cloudfront.net//wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Q20.png

In the link given above,
 varP and varQ are shared variables and both are initialized to false. Which one of the following statements is true?

1.The proposed solution prevents deadlock but fails to guarantee mutual exclusion

2.The proposed solution guarantees mutual exclusion but fails to prevent deadlock

3.The proposed solution guarantees mutual exclusion and prevents deadlock

4.The proposed solution fails to prevent deadlock and fails to guarantee mutual exclusion

According to the question setter 4th answer is the correct answer.

I have figured that it fails to guarantee mutual exclusion but how does it  fails to prevent deadlock?

Comment: Is this a homework question? And, do you have any thoughts? Asking someone to provide a complete answer without any of your own input is unlikely to bear fruit.

Comment: i have my own thoughts about mutual exclusion.I just need some elaboration on how deadlock freedom is not provided.One more thing,this is not a homework question.

Comment: In general, variable writes by one thread might never be seen by another thread without some sort of memory barrier. Therefore, deadlock.

Comment: What are the initial values of varP and varQ?

Comment: read carefully,initial values are mentioned.It is assumed there is no such barrier .

Comment: "It is assumed there is no such barrier" - I can see that there is no such barrier. Do you mean that it is assumed no such barrier is _required_ for variable writes to be visible to other threads? Is that fact that there is a 'while (true)' statement without a break relevant to the issue of deadlock? (Neither process will ever execute the "other code for process" as marked in the comment at the end).

Comment: It would really help me as well as the viewers if you stop beating around the bush.

Comment: I don't see how I am "beating around the bush". You haven't answered my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this after studying the algo carefully.

Say process Y has used the Critical Section.Therefore,it must have set VarQ variable as false.

Now if Process X tries to enter Critical Section.It can never enter unless Process Y also tries to enter.Reason being the condition while(varQ == true) will remain false unless Process Y tries to enter Critical Section and in doing so sets VarQ to true which before leaving Critical Section(CS) it had set to false.

So as we can see if Process Y does not tries to enter CS,Process X is indefinitely blocked and also the Critical Section is lying unused.

But the question still remains that how is lack of starvation freedom leading to lack of deadlock freedom.In deadlock every process is blocked,but if Process Y indeed tried to enter CS again,Process X could have been successful in its attempt to enter CS.